# clearInterval does not stop goes passed 0 (countdown)

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

This is just a simple setInterval example I am working with, but the clearInterval is not stopping the setInterval. It counts passed 0 to negitive numbers. How do I make this work and stop at 0?

```
    getMoreVideosCountdown = 10;
    getMoreVideos = setInterval(function() {
        console.log(getMoreVideosCountdown);
        if (getMoreVideos <= 0) {
            clearInterval(getMoreVideos);
        }
        getMoreVideosCountdown--;
    },1000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (getMoreVideos <= 0) {
```

should be

```
if (getMoreVideosCountdown <= 0) {
```

---

Currently, you're checking if the `interval identifier` gets lower or equals zero, which is never going to happen.